# Find a bound on the error of estimation

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation

> Telephone pollsters often interview between 1000 and 1500 individuals regarding their opinions on various issues. Does the performance of colleges’ athletic teams have a positive impact on the public’s perception of the prestige of the institutions? A new survey is to be undertaken to see if there is a difference between the opinions of men and women on this issue.
>
> (a). If 1000 men and 1000 women are to be interviewed, how accurately could you estimate the difference in the proportions who think that the performance of their athletics teams has a positive impact on the perceived prestige of the institutions? Find a bound on the error of estimation.
>
> (b). Suppose that you were designing the survey and wished to estimate the difference in a pair of proportions, correct to within .02, with probability .9. How many interviewees should be included in each sample?

For (a), I have no idea where to start since I'm just given n.

For (b), I want to use $Z_{\alpha/2}*\sigma_{\hat{\theta}}=B$, but I'm not given any value for $p$ to find $\sigma_{\hat{\theta}}$. What should I do?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

For (a), I imagine you should phrase your answer in terms of $Z_{\alpha/2}$ and $\sigma_{\hat{\theta}}$. It seems to be a theoretical question, so you won't have a number answer.

For (b), you should you $p=.5$, because this will maximize the value you get for $n$. Then given any different probability, you would be safe with this sample size.